# jQuery's setData/getData events should be capable of overriding $.data()'s default behavior... but how?

Tags: jquery, events

Check out the official blog post on the 1.4.3 release: http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/

I am thoroughly confused by this sentence (under "Events"):

> jQuery has already had setData and
>   getData events (which are broadcast
>   whenever data is set or gotten through
>   the .data() method) – overriding these
>   methods makes it possible to override
>   the default behavior for those
>   features (namely you can return a
>   different value or prevent a value
>   from being set).

1. "(...) had setData and getData events (...) - overriding these methods" -- which methods?!?
2. "makes it possible to override the default behavior" -- how?!? I have looked into the source and I cannot think of any way to either "return a different value" or "prevent a value from being set."

Anyone out there who knows more than me?

Comment: Good question. The jQuery docs say nothing, but you already know that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe to these events using the `setData` and `getData` events:

```
$(document.body).bind('setData', function(event, key, value) {
    console.log(key + ': ' + value);
});
```

This will log 'example: hello, world' when the following is called:

```
$('a:first').data('example', 'hello, world');
```

Unless I am completely misunderstanding how the code works, there is no way to change the default action, including `e.preventDefault();`.  See [the relevant lines in `data.js`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/data.js#L182), the source code for `$.fn.data`.